# class is an ambiguous reference between NameSpace1.Class and NameSpace2.Class

Tags: c#, ambiguous

I have web service (wcf c#) that uses entity framework.

It worked perfectly, but I updated the model and now I get error:

> class is an ambiguous reference between NameSpace1.Class and
> NameSpace2.Class.

I work in visualStudio 2012, and it suggests to change the type to NameSpace1.Class or NameSpace2.Class (Class is my class name and NameSpace1/2 are my namespaces names)

I choose the type I want - NameSpace1.Class, but then I get error:

> The type or namespace name 'NameSpace1' does not exist in the
> namespace.

but I dont understand - It **does** exist. and vs itself suggested me to choose it.

I tried everything: rebooting vs, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, and even rebooting my computer, but nothing helped.

maybe the error is wrong?

### edit

well, the error comes from this line:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetMyClassList()
```

the options are: NameSpace1.MyClass or NameSpace2.MyClass.

I Click on the first, and it changed to:

```
public IEnumerable<NameSpace1.MyClass> GetMyClassList()
```

and then get error :

The type or namespace name 'Class' does not exist in the namespace 'Bll.NameSpace1'.

I think, that maybe the error occures because I have the namespace NameSpace1 twice: one in Bll.NameSpace1 (Bll is my current project) and the second in Reference with the name NameSpace1.

Comment: *maybe the error is wrong?* very unlikely. It would help if you could post the relevant code.

Comment: what `using` statements do you have at the top of the code file? Are `NameSpace1` and `NameSpace2` the real names? If so, just change them to something *meaningful*.

Comment: Yes your edit makes sense. That is the point of namespacing - as far as possible they should be unique. I would try to rename `Bll.NameSpace1` to something more related to what is actually inside it, such as `Bll.BusinessEntities`

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio gives errors that aren't really errors. Try rebooting Visual Studio and if that doesn't help reboot your pc. Additionally, clean your solution.

Comment: thank you all. @Erwin, I mentioned I have done everything like rebooting and cleaning.

Comment: I did what you, @Rhumborl, and that was the solution. thanks again! what I don't understand is why it occured suddenly after updating the model - it has worked perfectly before.